# R Comparison of two SummarizedExperiment objects

Tags: r, unit-testing, comparison, r-s4, testthat

My unit test fails on comparing reference and expected `SummarizedExperiment` objects. Error message:

```
> expect_identical(target, current)
Error: `target` not identical to `current`.
Attributes: < Component “assays”: Class definitions are not identical >
```

**MWE:**

[LINK TO DATASET](https://drive.google.com/file/d/122_zcR8NZCrjqwR6Sm2n0m3I6nloGUWn/view?usp=sharing)

Code:

```
load("se-comparison.Rdata")
library(SummarizedExperiment)
library(testthat)

expect_identical(target, current)
# expect_identical() uses attr.all.equal() to compare S4 objects so check this
attr.all.equal(target, current)
# ok, check the attributes
cur <- attributes(current)
tar <- attributes(target)

class(cur$assays)
class(tar$assays)

expect_identical(
  cur$assays,
  tar$assays
)

expect_identical(
  class(cur$assays),
  class(tar$assays)
)
```

Output:

```
> library(SummarizedExperiment)
> library(testthat)
> expect_identical(target, current)
Error: `target` not identical to `current`.
Attributes: < Component “assays”: Class definitions are not identical >
> # expect_identical() uses attr.all.equal() to compare S4 objects so check this
> attr.all.equal(target, current)
[1] "Attributes: < Component “assays”: Class definitions are not identical >"
> # ok, check the attributes
> cur <- attributes(current)
> tar <- attributes(target)
> class(cur$assays)
[1] "ShallowSimpleListAssays"
attr(,"package")
[1] "SummarizedExperiment"
> class(tar$assays)
[1] "ShallowSimpleListAssays"
attr(,"package")
[1] "SummarizedExperiment"
> cur$assays
Reference class object of class "ShallowSimpleListAssays"
Field "data":
List of length 1
names(1): counts
> tar$assays
Reference class object of class "ShallowSimpleListAssays"
Field "data":
List of length 1
names(1): counts
> expect_identical(
+   cur$assays,
+   tar$assays
+ )
Error: cur$assays not identical to tar$assays.
Class definitions are not identical
> expect_identical(
+   class(cur$assays),
+   class(tar$assays)
+ )
>
```

Any ideas why comparison fails?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why it fails in general, but `attr.all.equal` compares class definitions returned by `getClass` method (if available). In this case, `getClass` for each `$assays` object returns class definition that differs in `fieldPrototypes` and `refMethods` (environment strings differ). This causes `identical` to fail.

Compare:

```
str(class(cur$assays))
str(cur$assays$getClass())
```

A workaround would be to skip checking attributes: `expect_equal(target, current, check.attributes = FALSE)`.

As a side note, this also works fine (note that I use here a getter method for SummarizedExperiment class instead of `$assays`):

```
expect_equal(
  assays(current),
  assays(target)
)
```